# rbindlist only elements that meet a condition

Tags: r, data.table, subset, rbindlist

I have a large list. Some of the elements are strings and some of the elements are data.tables. I would like to create a big data.table, but only rbind the elements that are data.tables.

I know how to do it in a for loop, but I am looking for something more efficient as my data are big and I need something quick.

Thank you!

```r
library(data.table)

DT1 = data.table(
  ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"),
  a = 1:6
)

DT2 = data.table(
  ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"),
  a = 11:16
)

list<- list(DT1,DT2,"string")
```

I am looking for a result similar to doing, but since I have many entries I cannot do it like this.

```r
rbind(DT1, DT2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sapply()` to generate a logical vector to subset your `list`

```
rbindlist(list[sapply(list, is.data.table)])
```

Answer (score 2):

`Filter` the `data.table` and `rbind`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(Filter(is.data.table, list_df))

#    ID  a
# 1:  b  1
# 2:  b  2
# 3:  b  3
# 4:  a  4
# 5:  a  5
# 6:  c  6
# 7:  b 11
# 8:  b 12
# 9:  b 13
#10:  a 14
#11:  a 15
#12:  c 16
```

**data**

```
list_df <- list(DT1,DT2,"string")
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot for your quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `keep` from `purrr` with `bind_rows`

```
library(tidyverse)
keep(list, is.data.table) %>%
   bind_rows
#    ID  a
# 1:  b  1
# 2:  b  2
# 3:  b  3
# 4:  a  4
# 5:  a  5
# 6:  c  6
# 7:  b 11
# 8:  b 12
# 9:  b 13
#10:  a 14
#11:  a 15
#12:  c 16
```

---

Or using `rbindlist` with `keep`

```
rbindlist(keep(list, is.data.table))
```